# Service with one login credential

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, identity, restful-authentication, asp.net-identity

I am developing a Rest service with Web API. The service only requires one login credential as it is used by an application developed by a third party. If I use the project template with "Individual User Accounts", I have to have a SQL server running(?), which is an overkill to support a single username and password. How about the LocalDB comes with VS 2013 ?
"Windows Authentication" cannot be used because the service is accessed from the Internet.

What is the proper way to authenticate ?. Are there any "in memory" or config file providers that come with Web API ? I know there is Asp.net Identity package, but It uses entity framework as a provider. Can anyone please suggest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom store for ASP.NET Identity and it could be memory or a config file.  [Here is a tutorial on creating a custom store in ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider).  I would not put it in memory because you will most likely want to change the password and that would require a recompile and redeploy. Personally I would just use SQL Express or SQL Compact as they take minimal resources and rewriting the data store seems like a lot of work for little benefit in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how do you want to authorize the call, the users has to be present in a database or cache to check the validity of the provided user. Microsoft will offer you out of the box a solution based on SQL server or some of their own products.

If you want to implement you own user check, you will probably have to take care of the authentication by yourself. This means that you will have to check the HTTP header by yourself and reject or accept the request by yourself.

My question is, why do you want to use some "in memory" provider? The users has to be somewhere. Why not a SQL express?